# Unclear foreign and primary keys

Tags: sql, database-design

I am very confused right now, maybe you can help me to understand the problem better.

There are two tables programmes and modules,

a program can have many modules and the same module may be in many programmes,

how would you identify primary and foreign keys here? because there is no single attribute that is unique, since the programme_id may appear n times as there are different modules in the same programme and module_id will appear multiple times as well, because it is present in many programmes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A programme will have a `programmeID` as its primary key

A module will have a `moduleID` as its primarykey

Then there will be a third table - say `ModuleProgrammes` - which has `moduleId` and `programmeID` as foreign keys.

ModuleProgrammes may have `moduleid` and `programmeid` as a primary key, or it may have a `moduleprogrammeid` as a primary key.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table for further information

Comment: thanks for help podiluska it's still quite confusing but this approach makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well simply for better design of database..Just user an another table and provide the references  of each primary key of the Programmes table and Modules table in new table as foriegn key which will reduce data redundancy and binds the tables as well..